# Entity Framework using await without ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

The following code works.

```
employees.AddRange(from e in DbContext.Employees
                   select new EmployeeSummaryModel
                   {
                       Name = e.Name,
                       Email = e.Email
                   });
```

But how would I rewrite this query to use `await`? Note that I don't want to use `ToListAsync()` as that unnecessarily creates a second list?

Comment: `AddRange` is inherently synchronous. The `IEnumerable<>` must already exists. What is `employees`? Does it contain any other data? Why not use `ToListAsync()` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: For our purposes, `employees` is a `List<EmployeeSummaryModel>`. But if I use `ToListAsync()`, I then have two lists (the one returned by `ToListAsync()` and the one I'm adding to). Although the list items would not be duplicated, the list would, as I tried to explain in the question. I'm trying to eliminate that waste.

Comment: Why not use *one* list, the one returned by `ToListAsync()`? The only reason to use it would be if it already contained other data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You're just going to have to trust me that I need to add it to an existing list. It is out of the scope of this site to explain everything I'm doing.

Comment: You could use `AsAsyncEnumerable() but you'd have to add items one by one. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm trying to add the results to an existing list without creating a second list.

Comment: I'm not sure how there are two lists here (or could be) .  That should be an expression tree until executed.

Comment: This doesn't explain much. Do you really want to use AddRange or is async iteration OK? *Both* are going to allocate new temporary buffers. It's not the lists that cost, it's the internal buffers

Comment: @JonathanWood _"I'm trying to eliminate that waste"_ Can you reasonably back up that the gains from not having that one list (which I'm not even sure remains after compiler optimization) outweighs the complexity of what you're trying to achieve? EF has never been built on the premise of performance, but rather on ease of use. If you want performance to such a degree, you shouldn't be using EF to begin with, rendering the question moot. On top of that, you seem to be ignoring the overhead of async task management, which is significantly bigger than that of having a single list in memory.

Comment: @BrettCaswell: `employees` is a list. And if I use `ToList()`, that's a second one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm not married to `AddRange()`. Again, I'm adding the results to an existing list. That's what I'm trying to do. I can't do anything about internal temporary buffers. But I don't need to create two `List<>`s.

Comment: @Flater: It is very possible to write either inefficient code or efficient code in C#. I don't really get your point. Async task allows my application to request the data without blocking the thread. That seems worthwhile to me. Creating a second list when I don't need does not.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I'm not saying there's no difference, I'm suggesting it's _negligible_. Not every grain of sand is worth the effort.

Comment: @Flater: No, but all grains of sand add up to something. It's my idea of a good programmer. You can of course decided what your idea of a good programmer is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AddRange` is inherently synchronous. There are multiple options to make this asynchronous, depending on how the results are used

**Just a single list**

One option would be to use the list returned by `ToListAsync` instead of creating a list in advance:

```
var employees= await query.ToListAsync();
```

There's no reason to have two lists if the first one is empty.

**Use async stream**

Another option is to use [AsAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asasyncenumerable?view=efcore-3.1) to execute the query asynchronously and get back an IAsyncEnumerable. This has to be iterated to copy the data to the existing list item by item:

```
await foreach(var emp in query.AsAsyncEnumerable())
{
    employees.Add(emp);
}
```

This is useful if the original list contains data already. Both `Add` and `AddRange` are going to cause reallocations of the list's internal buffer though.

**Use an empty list with capacity**

If you have even a rough idea of the number of results, you could create a list with a specific capacity and avoid at least some reallocations :

```
var employees=new List<Employee>(100);
await foreach(var emp in query.AsAsyncEnumerable())
{
    employees.Add(emp);
}
```

**Async pipeline**

If you have a lot of data though, you probably shouldn't be storing them in a list even temporarily. You could create a pipeline of methods that accept and return `IAsyncEnumerable` and process the data as they arrive, only caching them at the end. You could use [System.Linq.Async](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators)'s operators for this

```
query.AsAsyncEnumerable()
     .Select(emp=>EnrichFromApiAsync(emp,someUrl))
     ...
     .ToListAsync();
```

Or convert it to an `Observable` with `ToObservable()`, processing the final transformed data as it reaches the end of the pipeline

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how you can use `AddRange` in this case but with latest EF Core and C# 8.0 [async streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/generate-consume-asynchronous-stream) you can use [`AsAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asasyncenumerable?view=efcore-3.1) method resulting in:

```
    var query = ...;
    await foreach(var e in query.AsAsyncEnumerable())
    {
        employees.Add(e);
    }
```

Comment: Which is `ToListAsync` [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v3.1.8/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2014) without the `new` and `return` parts.

Comment: @IvanStoev: No, it isn't. `ToListAsync()` allocates and populates a `List<>`. This code populates my existing list.

Comment: @JonathanWood  this is exactly what i wrote. it is **without** the `new` (list) and `return` (list) parts

Comment: @IvanStoev: Well, ok. The `new` was what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: @JonathanWood The point was that you could easily make your owm extension method by copying the EF Core one, removing `new` and `return` parts and pass `list` as parameter :) Also it proves that this answer is in right direction.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Yes, his answer is exactly in the right direction. I guess I was confused by your comment. You seemed to be suggesting he wasn't going in the right directly, or even that `ToListAsync()` could be used instead. So perhaps that wasn't your point at all.

Comment: Indeed it wasn't. The intent was the exact opposite - like if the essential part of the EF Core implementation is the same as here, then this is the way to go.

Comment: For better performance you could consider avoiding restoring the sync context on every loop, by using the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.configureawait) extension method: `await foreach(var e in query.AsAsyncEnumerable().ConfigureAwait(false))`